# google-analytics-rails not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-analytics

I am using the google-analytics-rails gem, and my app is hosted on heroku. I am also using a regular domain name that points to the heroku app. I have done the configuration in the app like this

```
config/environments/production.rb:

# replace this with your tracker code
GA.tracker = "UA-xxxxxx-x"
```

app/views/layout/application.html.erb, in the  tag :

```
<%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? %>
```

and pushed to heroku, but am not seeing anything stats in GA. In my configuration at ga.google.com  should I point to myapp.heroku.com or the actual domain name? What other trouble shooting can I do to see if it is configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, try pointing to your actual domain name.

Comment: Is your analytics code actually rendering? Open the page source of your live site in a browser and see if it's there.

Comment: I have this is app.html.erb     <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? %> What should that look like in source? Here is what I see in source http://pastie.org/8531088

Comment: I mean the page source you see when you open your site in a web browser and you right-click -> view page source. Is there a google analytics javascript snippet in the place where you'd expect it?

Comment: Yes..thats what I pasted above. Thats what I am asking...should I see <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? %> in the source? Or does it get translated/converted to something else?

Comment: Yes your <%= analytics_init ... code should render a a google analytics html/javascript snippet like this one in the code sample: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Comment: erb tags <%= %> are only serverside, they get rendered to html when served to the browser.

Comment: OK, yes, when I view page source I am seeing the js code from the dev guide, but still not stats in my GA console. I'm flummoxed!